# SELECT 'random' results with set parameters

Tags: php, mysql

I am developing a system which selects questions from a database to generate a test/exam.

Each question has a set 'question type' ('**q_type**'). I have a database of questions and need to select 4 questions, each with a different 'q_type'.

The basic query to select 4 random questions at the moment is:

```
SELECT * FROM questions ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,4
```

This obviously does not take into account the fact that each question should have a different 'q_type'.

I would like to be able to do something that follows this logic (i need something to fill in the square brackets):

```
SELECT * FROM questions WHERE ['q_type' is DISTINCT] ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,4
```

I have tried using GROUP BY 'q_type', but that simply gives the first question for each 'q_type', not a different question of that type each time.

Any help would be great, as I am completely stumped at the moment (I am working with a overblown PHP loop which simply queries the DB 4 times, with an updated WHERE 'q_type'!=XX each time).

Thanks for any help!

Comment: nice question saulposel, I am also waiting for any solution by query.. :)

Comment: For N=4, you might get away with 4 nested SELECT's. Select the 2nd question WHERE q_type != 1st.q_type, select the 3rd question WHERE q_type != 2nd.q_type AND q_type != 1st.q_type, etc. Obviously non-scalable.

Comment: I agree. As there doesn't seem to be a pure mySQL option, you either do 4 nested queries as mentioned above or you do a mysql_fetch_assoc() loop as Fanis suggested. It's purely a performance/scale decision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's an easy way to do this with simple queries. You could probably do it with a mysql stored procedure, or to save some development time do it in php.

If the pool of questions isn't something extremely large, and this isn't something that happens too frequently, you should be ok with the 4 separate queries (one for each q_type), or even with getting the entire question set into php and then playing around with it to get 4 random questions, one in each q_type.

With the following (untested) code you'll be getting all questions ordered randomly and loop through them to get the first question for each q_type, then stop. It's not the most elegant solution but, again, for small enough data sets and frequency it should be ok.

```
$questions = array() ;
$res = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM questions ORDER BY RAND()') ;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {

    //if we have all 4, stop
    if (count($questions) == 4) {
        break ;
    }

    $currType = $row['q_type'] ;
    $currQuestion = $row['questionTitle'] ;

    if (isset($questions[$currType])) {
        //already have it, continue to the next
        continue ;
    }

    $questions[$currType] = $currQuestion ;

}
```

Comment: if (as it appears) there is no direct mySQL functionality to do this then depending on the number of questions total vs number of questions needed, then you either do individual queries or you loop through as you have suggested. I guess it a performance decision. Thanks for the suggested mysql_fetch_assoc() code, I havent used 'continue' and 'break' in a mysql_fetch_array loop before.

Answer (score 0):

i'm by no means an SQL expert but does this work?

```
SELECT DISTINCT `q_type`, * FROM questions ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0, 4
```

Comment: funnily enough I tried that, but it's not valid syntax. You seemingly can't do SELECT DISTINCT followed by another SELECT parameter.